# How to calculate difference between two days in hours in postgreSQL and return as days?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in days such that for hours from 1-23 we consider it as a day.
for example: `Date1 = '2021-06-15 01:52:00.926+00'`
`Date2 = '2021-06-15 02:52:00.926+00'`
Here, Date1-Date2 = 1hour. I want to take ceil of it to be 24hrs i.e 1 day.
I tried `(Date2::DATE - Date1::DATE)` but it gives 0.
There can be two scenarios: If difference between days is 35hrs it should return 3(i.e 3 days). If the difference between dates is 5hrs it should return 1(i.e 1 day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `epoch` arithmetic:

```
select ceiling(extract(epoch from date2) - extract(epoch from date1)) / (24 * 60 * 60)
from t;
```

Note that this particular formulation counts anything longer than 1 day as 2 days.  I *think* that is the intention of your question.  However, if you really do have a 1 hour buffer, the logic could be tweaked to handle that.

Comment: I tried `ceil((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM Date1- Date2)/3600)/24.0)`. What is the difference? Please explain.

Comment: One obvious difference is that `date2 > date1` in your sample data.  But that should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not technically an answer to your PostgreSQL question, however in Ingres (Postgres was the successor to Ingres) we have a interval function which returns the interval between two dates. Do you have anything similar in PostgreSQL?

e.g. `select interval('hours', date1 - date2)`

Comment: In postgres you can simply subtract two timestamps to obtain an interval.